# complex MySQL query wrong results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build complex mysql query but its returning wrong results...

```
SELECT
  b.name  AS batch_name,
  b.id    AS batch_id,

  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)
    AS total_students,

  COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    AS open_balance,

  SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
  ) AS gross_fee,

  SUM( COALESCE(i.discount, 0) )
    AS discount,

  COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    + SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
      )
    - SUM( COALESCE(i.discount, 0) )
    AS net_payable,

  SUM(  COALESCE(r.reg_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(r.tut_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(r.other_fee, 0)
  ) AS net_recieved,

  ( COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    + SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
      )
    - SUM(  COALESCE(i.discount,  0) )
  )
  - ( SUM(  COALESCE(r.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(r.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(r.other_fee, 0)
      )
    )
    AS balance_due

  FROM batches b
  LEFT JOIN students s ON s.batch      = b.id
  LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.student_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN recipts  r ON r.student_id = s.id

  WHERE s.inactive = 0
  GROUP BY b.name, b.id;
```

Returns following results...

```
| batch_name | total_students  | open_bal | gross_fee | discount | net_payable | net_recieved | due_balance |
+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|  MS        | 6               | 10000    | 0         | 0        | 10000       | 101000       | -91000      |
+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**batches table**

```
| id  | name |
+-----+------+
| 9   | Ms   |
+-----+------+
```

**Students table**

```
| id  | open_bal | batch | inactive |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 44  | -16000   | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 182 | 9000     | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 184 | -36000   | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 185 | 19000    | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 186 | 9000     | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| 187 | 4000     | 9     | 0        |
+-----+----------+-------+----------+
```

**Invoices Table**

```
| id   | student_id | reg_fee | tut_fee | other_fee | net_payable | discount |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
|      |            |         |         |           |             |          |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

No invoices are available for above students id.

**Recipts table**

```
| id   | student_id | reg_fee | tut_fee | other_fee | status     |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  8   | 44         | 0       | 0       | 1500      |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  277 | 44         | 0       | 50000   | 0         |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  26  | 182        | 0       | 0       | 1500      |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  424 | 182        | 0       | 15000   | 0         |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  468 | 182        | 0       | 15000   | 0         |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  36  | 185        | 0       | 0       | 1500      |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  697 | 185        | 0       | 15000   | 0         |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  66  | 187        | 0       | 0       | 1500      |  confirmed |
+------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Expected results using above sql query and tables...

```
| batch_name | total_students  | open_bal | gross_fee | discount | net_payable | net_recieved | due_balance |
+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|  MS        | 6               | -11000   | 0         | 0        | 10000       | 101000       | -112000     |
+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: "Complex Query + Wrong Result " Deadly combination

Comment: what u exact want?? and would u plz paste some data..so that we can experiment

Comment: No way to answer that without knowing anything about the structure of the tables or the data in them...

Comment: @diEcho ok i am going to paste some data

Comment: @Nikoloff i am going to add table structure, thanks for asking,

Comment: @diEcho data pasted, please have a look

Comment: @Nikoloff more details added, please have a look

Comment: @Brendan Bullen i have posted above in my question.

Comment: All I see are your expected results. What are the actual results?

Comment: Please check again, i have edited now.

Comment: Can you please tell how your net_payable will be  10000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution, i was joining lots of queries together and that's by some results are doubling. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't provided full information - no batches table, even the not existing recipts table.. Anyway, I assume we don't care whats in the batches table, lets say it's just the name and id. Your receipts table have multiple rows for the same student. This should result in multiple rows returned for the other tables as well, due to all the JOINs. Therefore you SUM()  multiple times values which must be summed just once, i.e. open_balance. This could be a clue as to where the problem is, I'd say you have to move the info that you need from 'the receipts table into subqueries, but I'm not sure you've shown us the entirety of your DB. Try removing the receipts table from the query and check the results again. If that's it, you should see what to do from there on or at least give more info to us.

**EDIT:**
The query should be:

```
SELECT
  b.name  AS batch_name,
  b.id    AS batch_id,

  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)
    AS total_students,

  COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    AS open_balance,

  SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
  ) AS gross_fee,

  SUM( COALESCE(i.discount, 0) )
    AS discount,

  COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    + SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
      )
    - SUM( COALESCE(i.discount, 0) )
    AS net_payable,
  SUM((SELECT SUM(COALESCE(receipts.reg_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(receipts.tut_fee,   0)
      + COALESCE(receipts.other_fee, 0)) FROM receipts WHERE receipts.student_id = s.id))
  AS net_recieved,

  ( COALESCE( SUM(s.open_bal), 0 )
    + SUM(  COALESCE(i.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(i.other_fee, 0)
      )
    - SUM(  COALESCE(i.discount,  0) )
  ) 
  - SUM((SELECT SUM(COALESCE(receipts.reg_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(receipts.tut_fee,   0)
          + COALESCE(receipts.other_fee, 0)) FROM receipts WHERE receipts.student_id = s.id)) 
    AS balance_due

  FROM batches b
  LEFT JOIN students s ON s.batch      = b.id
  LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.student_id = s.id
  WHERE s.inactive = 0
  GROUP BY b.name, b.id;
```

This will sum students data in the receipts table even if it's on more than one row, returning just one row. Removing the join to the receipts table removes duplicate lines from the other tables, so the calculations should now be correct.

One more thing - you've got `s.inactive = 0` in the WHERE clause, make sure it's not relevant to this calculations.

P.S. How come you don't know what a sub query is and you end up writing stuff like that?

Comment: yes if i remove recipts from query, it shows correct open_balance, how should i fix this? i don't have idea about sub queries, please help, thanks.

Comment: s.inactive = 0 is related to students table, its a Boolean to show if user if active or not.

Comment: Of course it is, it's just another thing worth mentioning, cause it can mess with the calculations

Comment: its returning correct value for open_bal but now its not giving correct value for net_received

Comment: I edited the post with the entire query pasted there, not just the corrections. You should've at least mentioned what the problem is.  You're not trying very hard to help fix you own problem.. I'll be offline for a while, hope that works. If not - check the results again and try to work on that, you now know what a sub query is.

Comment: thanks for yours help, but its still not giving correct value of open_bal for few batches. i have even updated students table in my question.